# How can I Access a Column by Name as a Variable to use the isin() Method

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have two dataframes as df1 and df2.
Both have the same column name as 'Accounts'.
I can currently access this data for comparison using the following code:
`df1.account.isin(df2.account.values)`

I would like 'account' to be accessed as a variable something like this.
`df1.[account].isin(df2.[account].values)`
After research I have discovered a possible solution as:
`df1.loc[:, 'account']` (I suspect this is not the correct approach.)

From this point, I'm not sure how to access the isin() method
As a result I welcome your wisdom with any alternative ways to accomplish this.
 Your help is very much appreciated :)
The full block of code is as follows:

```py
slgCSV = 'c:\\automation\\python\\a.csv'
armyCSV = 'c:\\automation\\python\\b.csv'
df1 = pd.read_csv(slgCSV)
df2 = pd.read_csv(armyCSV)
d3 = {'Expected': [], 'Actual': []}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=d3)
match1 = df1.account.isin(df2.account.values)
match2 = df2.account.isin(df1.account.values)
for r1 in df1[match1].index:
    for r2 in df2[match2].index:
        # print("R2: " + str(r2))
        if df1.account[r1] == df2.account[r2]:
            idx = df1.account[r1]
            row = {'Expected Row ID': r1+2, 'Actual Row ID': r2+2}
            print("Output: " + str(row) + ": " + str(idx))
```

df1 looks as follows:

```
Account
1
2
3
4
5
```

df2 looks as follows:

```
Account
3
1
5
2
4
```

The solution is as follows:
`col = "account"`
`df1[col].isin(df2[col].values)`
Thank you for all the help!

Comment: You're trying to select values in the `df1['account']` column if the values are in `df2['account']`?

Comment: correct a mundo =P , the problem is the column names change, and so I allow the user to pass in arguments to identify what column they wish to access for each csv.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: by all means, I will modify the original post with the source =)

Comment: I think @HS-nebula gave you the answer, just make the user defines `col = 'name_col_define_by_user'` and then do `df1[col].isin(df2[col].values)`, like this the column selected is the one from the user. If the names are not the same in both `df1` and `df2`, then make the user define `col1 = 'col_from_df1'` and , `col2 = 'col_from_df2'` and the code is `df1[col1].isin(df2[col2].values)`

Comment: I meant could you show us what `df1` and `df2` look like? And thanks @Ben.T, I didn't want to assume that without seeing some data.

Comment: Okay so I added a variable called: col = "account" , then I modified this line of code: match1 = exp.account.isin(act.account.values) ---- to this ---- match1 = exp.[col].isin(act.[col].values) , and it is now throwing a compiler error that reads: "name expected"

Comment: I figured out the issue, it is because I had a period between the dataframe and the open bracket, it works now, thank you very much for all of your help! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try.. using the set functionality

```
Usercol ='Account' #user entry
Common = 
list(set(df1.loc[:Usercol]).intersect(set(df2.loc[:Usercol])))
#fetch index of each data frame using
df1[df1[Usercol].isin(Common)].index
df2[df2[Usercol].isin(Common)].index
```

Comment: Hey bro thank ya for the input, this solution also worked, I appreciate your help! =)